# May I change mycompany.sharepoint.com to sharepoint.mycompany.com

Tags: sharepoint-online, domain

I would like to provice access to my primary SharePoint Online site collection, ie `mycompany.sharepoint.com` through my own domain name: `sharepoint.mycompany.com`.  I have configured the domain in Office 365 admin center. Is this possible? What are the steps?.

I have read [Rename your SharePoint Online Public Website address to use your custom domain](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Rename-your-SharePoint-Online-Public-Website-address-to-use-your-custom-domain-3d4bd288-772b-4f88-af4d-f025b3825ed3) but I have purshased Office 365 just today.. so I'm afraid this is not possible now. Please, can you confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can change is the public SharePoint site, you cannot change anything else.